# CSS not applied

Tags: python, html, css, django

Im having some issues in applying my CSS. (I'm using Django 1.5)

Here is my project structure:

```
project
   - app
   - project
   - static
       - css
           - style.css
   - template
       - index.html
```

My settings are default, apart from adding my db settings.

This is my index.html doing a ref to css:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"  />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My error was 404 for style.css location:

```
[24/May/2013 17:24:57] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1676
```

Appreciate if someone can let me know which part I have missed out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your settings are default it can't work i think. You have to tell Django where static files are served. You do that in the setting file.

This should be of help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/